# Laravel 5.3 Auth:attempt is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

Dont matter if i insert valid or invalid credentials, the user is always redirect to the route defined in RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware. My question: How can i redirect authenticated users to different route than non authenticated user?

RedirectIfAuthenticated (Middleware):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
```

This is my LoginController:

```
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

public function authenticate(Request $data){
    if (Auth::attempt( ['cnpj' => $data['cnpj'], 'password' => $data['password'] ] )){
        return redirect()->route('someroute');
    }
    else{
        return redirect()->route('login');

    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
}) -> name('/');

Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@create');

Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});

Route::get('/login', function (){
    return view('auth.login');
})->name('login');

Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@authenticate');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LoginController`, you have set the `guest` middleware to apply to all routes except for `logout`.  That means that a user who is authenticated can never get to the `authenticate` method because the middleware has already been run and has redirected the user.

The simplest fix would be to add the `authenticate` method to the exclusions for the `guest` middleware:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['logout', 'authenticate']]);
}
```

---

It appears from your question that you don't really understand Laravel's concepts of Middleware, Routing, and Authentication.  I highly recommend that you reread the documentation on those features, because it looks like you are trying to manually implement features that already exist in the framework.