# Login Fail in laravel 5.2 using AuthenticatesUsers trait

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm using the AuthenticatesUsers trait to handle logins in my web site.
When I register a new user on the site it can login and logout successfully, but when I login through the login form it fails every time even though I'm providing the right data. I don't understand why this is happening. What did I do wrong? Here is my auth controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{       

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    protected $guard = 'user';

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $data['firstName'],
            'last_name' => $data['lastName'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Route.php

```
<?php


Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // Your route here

//    // Authentication routes...
    Route::get('customer/login', 'Customer\Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('customer/login', 'Customer\Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('customer/logout', 'Customer\Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
//
//    // Registration routes...
    Route::get('customer/register', 'Customer\Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('customer/register', 'Customer\Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', function (){
        return view('welcome');
    });
});       

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: what you mean with it fails? an error or blank page? or what happens?

Comment: it showing "credential not match"

Comment: can you post your routes'? also try change this in constructor :  $this->middleware('auth'); instead of guest Middleware

Comment: i'ts a possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451427/laravel-5-3-authattempt-is-not-working

Comment: is it working on laravel 5.2 ??

Comment: it should be , because except accepts an array of routes, just try it and tell if it works! just a line! :D

Comment: nothing happening,no error showing.just redirect back to login page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127094/discussion-between-joaquin-javi-and-moin-khan).